# Magento2: different kind of composer.json files

Tags: magento2, module, composer, vendor

In Magento2 I see different vendors follow different composer.json formats given below to name their modules.
1st:

```
 "autoload": {
    "files": [ "registration.php" ],
    "psr-4": {
      "Amit\\SamplePage\\": ""
    }
  }
```

2nd:

```
   "extra": {
        "map": [
            [
                "*",
                "Amit/SamplePage"
            ]
        ]
    }
```

1. What's difference between them and which one I should follow?
2. `registration.php` is used to to register a module then why `composer.json` is needed in all modules ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is the way to go:

```
"autoload": {
    "files": [ "registration.php" ],
    "psr-4": {
      "Amit\\SamplePage\\": ""
    }
  }
```

The map function in Composer:

```
   "extra": {
        "map": [
            [
                "*",
                "Amit/SamplePage"
            ]
        ]
    }
```

forces the extension to be installed in `app/code`. This was used in older beta's of Magento 2. Although this will work, it's not the way Magento loads extensions anymore. If you do not use the map function the extension will be installed in the vendor folder, as it should be.

`registration.php` defines the type: theme or extension and registers your theme/extension in Magento 2.

The `composer.json` file is added so the extension can be loaded via Composer. It also handles the autoloading for your extension.

Comment: [registration.php](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/component-registration.html) reference.